# Clojure: Beginners question on passing vectorized string to function

Tags: clojure

I'm new to Clojure.  I was trying to get the following code to generate anagrams of the word 'rat'.
Ideally I'd like to start with a string, convert it to a vector -- but for now I tried starting with a vector.  I've tried many variants and getting compiler errors.  I understand what the errors mean -- but not sure what to do in clojure to fix them.  The current code produces this error: "clojure.lang.PersistentVector cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IAtom".

```
(ns clojure.examples.anagram
(:gen-class))

(defn generatePermutations [v n] 
   (if (zero? n) 
      (do (println (apply str v)) v) 

      (loop [i 0 a v] 
         (if (< i n) 
            (do 
               (let [a (generatePermutations a (dec n))] 
               (recur (inc i) (swap! a (if (even? n) 0 i) n)))) 
            (generatePermutations a (dec n)))))) 

(let [word (vec ['r' 'a' 't'])]
   (generatePermutations word 3))
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Here is the java version of the code.  This version takes the word "rat" (or 
any other word) as a command line argument.  For the Clojure version, I was running it in an online IDE and there wasn't an easy way to pass an argument so I was attempting to hardcode the input.

```
public class Anagram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length !=1) {
            System.err.println("Exactly one argument is required");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        String word = args[0];
        generatePermutations(word.toCharArray(),word.length()-1);
    }

    private static void generatePermutations(char[] a, int n){
        if (n ==0){
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(a));
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                generatePermutations(a, n-1);
                swap(a,n%2 == 0?0: i, n);
            }
            generatePermutations(a,n-1);
        }
    }

    private static void swap (char[] a, int i, int j){ 
        char saved = a[i];
        a[i]= a[j];
        a[j] = saved;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just in case you're interested in this, try reading and understanding https://github.com/clojure/math.combinatorics/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/math/combinatorics.cljc . It has a `permutations` function, too. A lot to digest for a Clojure beginner, but also a lot to learn from.

Answer (score 1):

```
Execution error (ClassCastException) at user/generatePermutations (REPL:55).
clojure.lang.PersistentVector cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IAtom
```

the problem, as error description says, is that you're trying to call `swap!` on a non atom value. To "update" the vector, you should rather use `assoc`.
So, in your case, simply replacing `swap!` with `assoc` makes it work.

you can read more on what is `atom` and how to use it [here](https://www.braveclojure.com/zombie-metaphysics/)

**update**

the example provided shows my mistake: 
the swap! was intended to be swap 2 elements in vector.

this can be done this way:

```
(defn swap [data-v i j]
  (assoc data-v
         i (data-v j)
         j (data-v i)))
```

so your initial function works (up to some extent):

```
user> (generatePermutations (vec "rat") 3)
;; rat
;; art
;; tra
;; rta
;; atr
;; tar
Execution error (IndexOutOfBoundsException) at user/swap (REPL:1423).
null
```

it fails when it tries to call `(swap a 0 3)`.

**update 2**

another problem, is that you call `(generatePermutations (vec "rat") 3)` , while in java version you do it with `word.length() - 1`. and indeed `(generatePermutations (vec "rat") 2)` gives you the result you expect.

Though it looks correct now, still it is not really 'clojure' way to solve this kind of tasks, i guess.

Comment: Thanks.  That does eliminate the compiler error but it doesn't produce the right output.  For example, my Java, Ruby, Python variants of this code produce:
rat
art
tra
rta
atr
tar

But when I replace swap! with assoc it produces a different output that muddles up numbers and letters -- gradually replacing the letters with their positional numbers: eg..,
1AT etc.

Comment: could you please provide the java or python variant then. Because the logic is unclear here: it's difficult to disjoint syntax and logic errors here :).

Comment: Sure.  This one is from Java.

Comment: Thanks!  It took me a while to realize that I could edit my original question -- so was struggling with the code formatting in the comment.  The java example is in the original question now.  MANY thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'll try to figure out that final swap.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to propose a more functional way to compute permutation. The code is denser and may seem obscur at first sight, but I think it comply better with the Clojure spirit.

```
(defn except-nth [coll idx]
  (let [v (vec coll)]
    (if (< idx (count v))
      (vec (concat (subvec v 0 idx) (subvec v (inc idx))))
      v)))

(defn permutation [v]
  (if (<= (count v) 1)
    (list v)

    (apply
     concat
     (for [idx (range (count v))]
       (map
        (fn [sub-permut] (vec (cons (get v idx) sub-permut)))
        (permutation (except-nth v idx))
        )))))
```

The `except-nth` function is just a helper function. It returns a vector without the element at the `idx` position. For example:

```
(except-nth (range 4) 1)
;; => [0 2 3]
```

The `permutation` function takes a collection and return a list of every possible permutations. Here are some example of results:

```
(permutation [42])
;; => ([42])

(permutation (vec (range 3)))
;; => ([0 1 2] [0 2 1] [1 0 2] [1 2 0] [2 0 1] [2 1 0])

(permutation (vec "ab"))
;; => ([\a \b] [\b \a])

(permutation ["foo" "bar" 42])
;; => (["foo" "bar" 42] ["foo" 42 "bar"] ["bar" "foo" 42] ["bar" 42 "foo"] [42 "foo" "bar"] [42 "bar" "foo"])
```

For a beginner, one of the must important thing, is to put in place a local REPL environment. It will help to play around with small code and to study new ones. Coming from the Java land, the code of `permutation` can be confusing for the following reasons:

- it's a recursive function
- a none trivial use of the `map` function
- the `for` keyword here doesn't refer to a 'usual' for loop but to [list comprehension syntax](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5lvV9ICwaMo)
- usage of the higher order function `apply`

For all these reasons, playing around in a REPL is important. If you need resources to learn quickly and in a funny way, I highly recommend [Clojure for the Brave and True](https://www.braveclojure.com/clojure-for-the-brave-and-true/) and to do some exercice on the [4Clojure website](http://www.4clojure.com/).
You can also find many videos about the resolution/discussion of 4Clojure problem on the [Practicalli youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCLsiVY-kWVH1EqgEtZiREJw).